# android configure DrawerLayout fading

Tags: android, drawerlayout

how do i configure the animation of the fading of what is currently showing on screen?
more specifically, when the drawer finishes opening, the rest of the screen, is completely black.
I want to configure the animation so that it's not completely black, but still darker than usual, like in youtube for example.
thanks very much in advance

Comment: Try `mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(yourColor);`